# Why I got Invalid datetime format uploading app on server?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Uploading my laravel 8 app to server with PHP 8.1.1 and testing row inserting
I got error, which I do not have at my local server :

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2022-06-21 14:49:54+00:00' for column 'updated_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `pages` (`name`, `slug`, `lang`, `languages`, `status`, `redirect_url`, `colors`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2w2, hgfhgf, en, ["en"], 0, http://site.test/pages_redirect, {"main_color":"#3a57e8"}, 2022-06-21 14:49:54+00:00, 2022-06-21 14:49:54+00:00))
```

table is created with migration :

```
Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Model has no any timestamp definitions.
In .env I have :

```
timezone='UTC'
```

In config/app.php I also have :

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

I can not get where "+00:00" is here in  error description  and how can it be fixed?

**Additive info :**
Php info on my server shows :

```
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    UTC
```

If in phpmyadmin to run :

```
SHOW VARIABLES where variable_name = 'time_zone'
```

I got values :

```
time_zone = SYSTEM
```

In the config/app.php I have hardcoded :

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is your server in a different timezone? Try setting timezone to

```
timezone='UTC+0:00'
```

and respectively

```
'timezone' => 'UTC+0:00'
```

Comment: Do you mean to make changes in php.ini of my site or in config/app.php of my app ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use yyyy/mm/dd h:mm format beacuse i had same error once and when i use that format it worked!

Comment: Where can I change this format ? On laravel/mysql side ?

Comment: In mysql..you can export table as csv and edit it using excel..in the excel you can change date format then save it and upload it again but pls keep a table sql backup in case of emergency you can upload it again..and make sure to delete all table data NOT DATABSE before upload new csv file.